# Importing contacts from the top webmail services

Tags: web-services, import-contacts

Is anyone familiar with a service or open-source scripts that can import contacts from Gmail, Yahoo mail, AOL, Hotmail and other prominent webmail services? (Not plaxo, it has a problem in IE7)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a one off operation. Linkedn can, but I'm not sure if you could do anything useful afterwards with the list.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution I can integrate into a web project I'm working on.